# Integrating virtual keyboard on a HP TouchSmart with an Adobe AIR app

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, touchscreen, virtual-keyboard

Does anyone know if it's possible to integrate the ToushSmart's virtual keyboard with an Adobe AIR application?

In most programs (Internet Explorer, Firefox, etc), when a user touches a text field a little keyboard icon automatically pops up which, when pressed, will bring up the virtual keyboard. However, this doesn't happen when clicking on text input fields in Adobe AIR applications.

Has anyone had any experience working with AIR/Flash and touchscreens? Is there any API that can tell Windows (or the HP virtual keyboard specifically) that the user has clicked in a text field and that the virtual keyboard should be shown? The text fields are the standard kind (fl.controls.TextInput).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try compiling your project as "accessible"? This is designed for things like screen readers, but it may hook into the same API that's used by the "virtual keyboard". Sorry I don't know where this setting is, should be in project/compiler settings somewhere.

Comment: Thanks! That ended up working - I set the accessibilityProperties on each text field and then called Accessibility.updateProperties() and that was sufficient to get the keyboard to recognize them.